# UISearchController causes black screen Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a strange problem in **iOS 9 with Swift 2.0**. I added `UISearchController` in my `tableViewController` but it causes a strange **black screen** problem. When I press the search bar and write something it shows my filtered results without any problem but when I tap another tab bar button like **Bookmarks** and after that when I tap tableViewController which is **Most Viewed** again it shows black screen like screen shot.

There is my **tableViewController**;

```
import UIKit

class CitiesTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

// MARK: - Class Properties

private var cities = [String]()
private var veterinaries = [Veterinary]()
private var filteredVeterinaries = [Veterinary]()
private var resultSearchController: UISearchController!

// MARK: - TableViewController Life Cycle Methods

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.getCitiesList()
    self.configureResultsSearchController()
}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    self.resultSearchController.active = false
}

// MARK: - Configuring Search Bar Controller

private func configureResultsSearchController() {
    self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.resultSearchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    self.resultSearchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Klinik veya ilçe adı"
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.resultSearchController.searchBar
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int { return 1 }
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if self.resultSearchController.active { return self.filteredVeterinaries.count }
    else { return self.cities.count }
}

// MARK: - Table view Delegate Methods

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(Constants.ShowDetailViewControllerSegueIdentifier, sender: nil)
    } else {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(Constants.ShowTownsTableViewControllerSegueIdentifier, sender: nil)
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Constants.CellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.filteredVeterinaries[indexPath.row].name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.filteredVeterinaries[indexPath.row].address
        return cell
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.cities[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}

// MARK: - PARSE Query Methods

private func getCitiesList() {
    let parseQueries = ParseQueries()
    parseQueries.downloadListData() {
        (let parseResults) in
        if let veterinaries = parseResults as? [Veterinary] {
            self.veterinaries = veterinaries
            for vet in veterinaries {
                if let city = vet.city {
                    self.cities.append(city)
                }
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.cities = HelperMethods().removeDuplicatesAndSort(array: self.cities)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - UISearchController Delegate Methods

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    self.filteredVeterinaries.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    if let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text{
        let searchText = searchBarText.lowercaseString
        // Searching with Veterinary Name and Veterinary City
        self.filteredVeterinaries = self.veterinaries.filter({$0.name?.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searchText) != nil})
        self.filteredVeterinaries += self.veterinaries.filter({$0.town?.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searchText) != nil})
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

This is the black screen image from iOS 9 simulator same as real device.
[image]

I think its deiniting my tableView when I tap the searchBar and it can't init again. Is this a bug or something ?

How can I solve this problem ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Friend, in your `viewDidLoad()` insert this code line:

```
self.definesPresentationContext = true
```

See how I put (line 29):

[click here to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiKKj.png)

Comment: Thats the trick i think. I solved the black screen issue thanks to you !

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same issue and I could fix it easily.
`self.definesPresentationContext = true` was already defined in **viewDidLoad()** but it didn't solve this issue.

In the above question, maybe you show `CitiesTableViewController` directly when you tap **MostViewed** tabbar item.

In order to avoid the black screen, you can embed **CitiesTableViewController**  in a UINavigationController and try to show the navigationcontroller when tapping the tabbar item.

This solution will avoid the black screen issue.