# View controller isn't called when back from another view using tab bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a simple application with `two controllers,` the navigation between which is carried out through the UITabBarController. When the application starts, everything works as it should, when it is initialized for the first time, but when I change something in the first VC and switch to second VC, and then try again to return to the first VC - it does not appear.

`ViewWillAppear()` addition didn't work in my case, because debugger didn’t even show that the `ViewDidLoad()` or `ViewWillAppear()` functions worked in the first VC.

[Thats how its look (CloudApp record)](https://share.getcloudapp.com/eDu9kv8G)

**MainTabBarController code:**

```
class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController {

  var photosVC: PhotosCollectionViewController!
  var likesVC: LikesCollectionViewController!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
  }

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    photosVC = PhotosCollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: WaterfallLayout())
    likesVC = LikesCollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())

    viewControllers = [
      generateNavigationController(rootViewController: photosVC, title: "Photos", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "photos")),
      generateNavigationController(rootViewController: likesVC, title: "Favourites", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "heart"))
    ]
  }

  override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    if (self.selectedViewController?.isKind(of: UINavigationController.self))!
    {
      let nav = self.selectedViewController as! UINavigationController
      nav.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
    }
  }

  private func generateNavigationController(rootViewController: UIViewController, title: String, image: UIImage) -> UIViewController {
    let navigationVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)
    navigationVC.tabBarItem.title = title
    navigationVC.tabBarItem.image = image
    return navigationVC
  }
}
```

**PhotosCollectionVC code:**

```
import UIKit

class PhotosCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

  var networkDataFetcher = NetworkDataFetcher()
  private var timer: Timer?

  private var photos = [UnsplashPhoto]()

  private var selectedImages = [UIImage]()

  //    private let itemsPerRow: CGFloat = 2 // относится к UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
  //    private let sectionInserts = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 20) // относится к UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

  private lazy var addBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem = {
    return UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addBarButtonTapped))
  }()

  private lazy var actionBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem = {
    return UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .action, target: self, action: #selector(actionBarButtonTapped))
  }()

  private var numberOfSelectedPhotos: Int {
    return collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.count ?? 0
  }

  private let enterSearchTermLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Please enter search term above..."

    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
  }()

  private let spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView = {
    let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .gray)
    spinner.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return spinner
  }()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    setupNavigationBar()
    setupCollectionView()
    setupSearchBar()
    setupEnterLabel()
    setupSpinner()
  }

  private func undateNavButtonsState() {
    addBarButtonItem.isEnabled = numberOfSelectedPhotos > 0
    actionBarButtonItem.isEnabled = numberOfSelectedPhotos > 0
  }

  func refresh() {
    self.selectedImages.removeAll()
    self.collectionView.selectItem(at: nil, animated: true, scrollPosition: [])
    undateNavButtonsState()
  }

  // MARK: - NavigationItems action

  @objc private func addBarButtonTapped() {
    print(#function)
    let selectedPhotos = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.reduce([], { (photosss, indexPath) -> [UnsplashPhoto] in
      var mutablePhotos = photosss
      let photo = photos[indexPath.item]
      mutablePhotos.append(photo)
      return mutablePhotos
    })

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "\(selectedPhotos!.count) фото будут добавлены в альбом", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let add = UIAlertAction(title: "Добавить", style: .default) { (action) in
      let tabbar = self.tabBarController as! MainTabBarController
      let navVC = tabbar.viewControllers?[1] as! UINavigationController
      let likesVC = navVC.topViewController as! LikesCollectionViewController

      likesVC.photos.append(contentsOf: selectedPhotos ?? [])
      likesVC.collectionView.reloadData()

      self.refresh()
    }
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Отменить", style: .cancel) { (action) in
    }
    alertController.addAction(add)
    alertController.addAction(cancel)
    present(alertController, animated: true)
  }

  @objc private func actionBarButtonTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    print(#function)

    let shareController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: selectedImages, applicationActivities: nil)


    shareController.completionWithItemsHandler = { _, bool, _, _ in
      if bool {
        self.refresh()
      }
    }

    shareController.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = sender
    shareController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = .any
    present(shareController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  // MARK: - Setup UI Elements

  private func setupCollectionView() {
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .white

    collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CellId")
    collectionView.register(PhotosCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: PhotosCell.reuseId)

    collectionView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 16, bottom: 0, right: 16)
    collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .automatic
    collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true

    if let waterfallLayout = collectionViewLayout as? WaterfallLayout {
      waterfallLayout.delegate = self
    }
  }

  private func setupEnterLabel() {
    collectionView.addSubview(enterSearchTermLabel)
    enterSearchTermLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    enterSearchTermLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
  }

  private func setupSpinner() {
    view.addSubview(spinner)
    spinner.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    spinner.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
  }

  private func setupNavigationBar() {
    let titleLabel = UILabel(text: "PHOTOS", font: .systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .medium), textColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.5019607843, green: 0.4980392157, blue: 0.4980392157, alpha: 1))
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: titleLabel)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [actionBarButtonItem, addBarButtonItem]
    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
    actionBarButtonItem.isEnabled = false
    addBarButtonItem.isEnabled = false
  }

  private func setupSearchBar() {
    let seacrhController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    navigationItem.searchController = seacrhController
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    seacrhController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    seacrhController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    seacrhController.searchBar.delegate = self
  }

  // MARK: - UICollecionViewDataSource, UICollecionViewDelegate

  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    enterSearchTermLabel.isHidden = photos.count != 0
    return photos.count
  }


  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: PhotosCell.reuseId, for: indexPath) as! PhotosCell
    let unspashPhoto = photos[indexPath.item]
    cell.unsplashPhoto = unspashPhoto
    return cell
  }

  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    undateNavButtonsState()
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! PhotosCell
    guard let image = cell.photoImageView.image else { return }
    selectedImages.append(image)

  }

  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    undateNavButtonsState()
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! PhotosCell
    guard let image = cell.photoImageView.image else { return }
    if let index = selectedImages.firstIndex(of: image) {
      selectedImages.remove(at: index)
    }
  }
}

// MARK: - UISearchBarDelegate

extension PhotosCollectionViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

  func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    print(searchText)
    self.spinner.startAnimating()
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: false, block: { (_) in
      self.networkDataFetcher.fetchImages(searchTerm: searchText) { [weak self] (searchResults) in
        guard let fetchedPhotos = searchResults else { return }
        self?.spinner.stopAnimating()
        self?.photos = fetchedPhotos.results
        self?.collectionView.reloadData()
        self?.refresh()
      }
    })
  }
}

// MARK: - WaterfallLayoutDelegate
extension PhotosCollectionViewController: WaterfallLayoutDelegate {
  func waterfallLayout(_ layout: WaterfallLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let photo = photos[indexPath.item]
    return CGSize(width: photo.width, height: photo.height)
  }
}
```

**LikesCollectionVC code:**

```
import UIKit

class LikesCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

  var photos = [UnsplashPhoto]()

  private lazy var trashBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem = {
    return UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .trash, target: self, action: nil)
  }()

  private let enterSearchTermLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "You haven't add a photos yet"
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
  }()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
    collectionView.register(LikesCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: LikesCollectionViewCell.reuseId)
    collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

    let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1

    setupEnterLabel()
    setupNavigationBar()

  }

  // MARK: - Setup UI Elements

  private func setupEnterLabel() {
    collectionView.addSubview(enterSearchTermLabel)
    enterSearchTermLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    enterSearchTermLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
  }

  private func setupNavigationBar() {
    let titleLabel = UILabel(text: "FAVOURITES", font: .systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .medium), textColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1))
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: titleLabel)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = trashBarButtonItem
    trashBarButtonItem.isEnabled = false
  }

  // MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource

  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    enterSearchTermLabel.isHidden = photos.count != 0
    return photos.count
  }

  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: LikesCollectionViewCell.reuseId, for: indexPath) as! LikesCollectionViewCell
    let unsplashPhoto = photos[indexPath.item]
    cell.unsplashPhoto = unsplashPhoto
    return cell
  }
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
extension LikesCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = collectionView.frame.width
    return CGSize(width: width/3 - 1, height: width/3 - 1)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nikita,
how did you setup your UITabBarController? With a storyboard or in code?
When you did it programmatically, can you share the code with us?

Comment: @ChristophP sure, already done it. And yes, programmatically.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40797252/8474654 this answer solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

> the navigation between which is carried out through the UITabBarController.

No, that is not what you are doing. Your tab bar controller does not navigate between your two view controllers. It navigates between two navigation controllers.

And that’s the problem. You cannot detect anything in viewDidAppear because your view controller is not what appears when the tab controller switches. What appears is the navigation controller.

Comment: I assumed that somewhere in the navigation there was a problem, but for the day of searching, I still did not find an answer on the network that would help me.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This is the first time I am using a tab bar, so I am still not good at working with it. Maybe you have any advice how can I solve my problem? I would be doubly grateful.

Comment: What problem? You have shown a lot of unnecessary code but you have not described any single thing that you want to do. If you want specific advice, be specific.